# I cannot configuration the IMAP into PHP extensions

Tags: php, php-extension

I cannot configuration the IMAP into PHP extensions.

I follow [Add IMAP PHP Extension](https://local.getflywheel.com/community/t/add-imap-php-extension/2382/2):

Because I am in CentOS 7, I replace the

> apt-get install -y libc-client-dev libkrb5-dev

to

```
yum install -y uw-imap-devel libc-client  
yum -y install krb5-server krb5-libs
```

and my configure is bellow:

```
./configure \
        --prefix=/usr/local/php-${php_version} \
        --with-config-file-path=/usr/local/php-${php_version}/etc \
        --enable-fpm \
        --with-fpm-user=www \
        --with-fpm-group=www \
        --with-mysqli \
        --with-pdo-mysql \
        --with-libdir=lib64 \
        --with-iconv-dir \
        --with-freetype-dir \
        --with-jpeg-dir \
        --with-png-dir \
        --with-zlib \
        --with-libxml-dir=/usr \
        --enable-xml \
        --disable-rpath  \
        --enable-bcmath \
        --enable-shmop \
        --enable-sysvsem \
        --enable-inline-optimization \
        --with-curl \
        --enable-mbregex \
        --enable-mbstring \
        --enable-ftp \
        --with-gd \
        --enable-gd-native-ttf \
        --with-openssl \
        --with-mhash \
        --enable-pcntl \
        --enable-sockets \
        --enable-opcache \
        --with-xmlrpc \
        --enable-zip \
        --enable-soap \
        --without-pear \
        --with-gettext \
        --disable-fileinfo \
        --enable-maintainer-zts \
        --with-kerberos \
        --with-imap-ssl \
```

but after `make & make install`, in the `/usr/local/php-7.1.16/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20160303/` do not exists the `imap.so`:

```
# cd /usr/local/php-7.1.16/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20160303/
[root@localhost no-debug-zts-20160303]# ls
opcache.a  opcache.so
```